# Why setVisibility() function has no definition?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, textview

Many funtions don't have a definition in my IDE and that's really frustrating and now I am struggling with the setVisibility() function. I am doing android programming in xamarin, visual studio using c#. I want to make a textview invisible when I click a specific button. I want to write the following:

```
TextView mytextview = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.mytextview);
button1.Click += delegate
    {mytextview.setVisibility(view.Invisible);};
```

I am getting an error that setVisibility has no definition and a red line under

```
setVisibility(view.Invisible)
```

How can I fixe this issue and is there are alternatives for making textview invisible ?

Comment: Perhaps `mytextview.SetVisible(false);`?

Comment: I can't find the SetVisible() also in my IDE @DavidG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use it like this:

```
mytextview.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
```

and to use the `ViewStates` enum you need to add the `Android.Views` namespace at the top of your Activity/Fragment class.

```
using Android.Views;
```

I suggest you to follow this nice [tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/hello,android/hello,android_quickstart/) for Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. But can I know why can't I use this function setVisibility() and why some functions have no definition in my IDE ? @apineda

Comment: setVisibility is the Android native way (Java) of doing what I suggested you to do. Xamarin guys translated many of the methods found in the Android SDK into a more C#-ish way. So if you are coming from a Android Java background you just need to find/learn the translation of these methods and properties.

Comment: Understood. Can you tell me where can I find or learn the translations of these methods ?

Comment: Visual Studio has a nice intellisense and looking at what is available for each object should be easy. If something starts with get or set in Java then most likely in C# these are Properties instead of methods.

Comment: Now, I am struggling with getText() funtion. I need to get the text from and editText but getTest() function is not working. @SKall

Comment: as @SKall indicated most of the getFunction() and setFunction are translated into Properties. In your case is just `Text`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
    `mytextview.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;`
if i don't remember wrong it should have solve that.

Comment: ViewStates is not available also in my IDE

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the caps so it looks like this. In Android Studio, that is the only possible way to make it invisible without getting an error while coding.

```
.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Other alternatives:

```
.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) //Default
.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

The difference between GONE and INVISIBLE is that GONE doesn't occupy any space, whereas INVISIBLE, just makes it, well, literally invisible...

Comment: What do you mean by caps ? The setVisibility() is not available in my IDE. When I write .setVi it is not giving me the possibility of setVisibility() in the IDE.

Comment: Oh, then I suppose I can't help you. I'm sorry :( Isn't changing to Android Studio a possiblility?

Comment: I don't think so cause Android Studio doesn't support c# language.